# Confirm quit only for keyboard shortcut, not for window close via mouse

Tags: key-bindings, quitting

I activated `setq-local confirm-kill-emacs (quote y-or-n-p)` on a hook for a local mode which has a shortcut very similar to `C-x C-c`, in order to avoid accidentally closing Emacs when trying to execute the said shortcut. That way, Emacs will ask me to confirm it and I will be able to cancel it.

But this has an unfortunate consequence, that is, when I click on the close button on the top of Emacs' window, it also asks the same question. This is often annoying.

Is there a way to only ask for confirmation when using the keyboard shortcut, but not the mouse click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may define a separate command for `C-x C-c` like:

```el
(defun keyboard-kill-emacs ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((confirm-kill-emacs 'yes-on-no-p)) ; temporarily enable the confirmation
    (save-buffers-kill-emacs)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-c") 'keyboard-kill-emacs)
```

Comment: Thanks, i'd edit it to fix the typo (`yes-or-no-p`) but it's below the 6-character minimum edit. Also, for lazy people, I'd add the code to put it as a hook to a local mode:
`(add-hook 'whatever-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (local-set-key (kbd "C-x C-c") 'keyboard-kill-emacs)))`
In any case, it worked just as intended, thanks.